# Cloud nine Vs. Dante's Inferno!

Tags: etymology, expressions, idioms

I looked for the expression to **be on cloud nine** on [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cloud%20nine&searchmode=none); it is stated 'of uncertain origin or significance'.

My question is could there be a connection between the origin of **cloud nine** and Dante's Inferno which is depicted as a hell  having **nine** concentric circles  -- in other words, cloud nine is heaven vs. Dante's hell.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-cloud-nine.html) the origin is less literary than the one you are suggesting:

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20cloud%20nine%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20cloud%20nine%3B%2Cc0): on cloud nine.

> - **It seems that it is the clouds themselves, rather than the number of them, that were in the thoughts of those who coined this phrase.** The imagery was originally of a 'cloud cuckoo land' or 'head in the clouds' dreaminess, induced by either intoxication or inspiration, rather than the 'idyllic happiness' that we now associate with the phrase. The early references all come from mid 20th century USA and the earliest that I've found is in Albin Pollock's directory of slang, The Underworld Speaks, 1935:
>
>   - "Cloud eight, befuddled on account of drinking too much liquor."
> - 'Cloud nine' comes a little later, for example, in The Oxnard Press-Courier, August 1946:
>
>   - "I think he has thought of everything, unless the authorities pull something new on him out of cloud nine."
> - Around the same period we find clouds seven and thirty-nine, in The San Mateo Times, April 1952 and Ross’s Hustlers, 1956, respectively:
>
>   - "Mantovani's skilled use of reeds and strings puts this disc way up on Cloud Seven."
>   - "That stuff is way up on Cloud Thirty-nine."
> - The early favourite was 'cloud seven' and many of the oldest citations use that form, as in this piece from The Dictionary of American Slang, 1960, which was the first printed definition of the term
>
>   - "Cloud seven - completely happy, perfectly satisfied; in a euphoric state."
> - This early preference for seven as the significant number may have been influenced by the existing phrase 'seventh heaven'.
> - **Since the 1980s or so, 'cloud nine' has become predominant. That has probably been influenced by the use of 'cloud nine' in popular music** - George Harrison adopted the term as the title of his 1987 album and, more notably, The Temptations' 'psychedelic soul' album of the same name, in 1969.